# SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage sends too many sms-xamarin

Tags: android, mono

I have an app which is an activity and a broadcast receiver which is have registered it in the manifest and the activity is destroyed at some point.

What does this broadcast receiver do is that it listens to incoming SMS and if the sender is the same as a number (which the user specifies in the activity) it sends an empty SMS to that number (both numbers are the same). I have compiled it with Android 2.3 but there are 2 problems.

1 - The application sends too many messages to that number after receiving one message.

2 - The abortbroadcast() is not working.
This is my broadcast receiver:

```
namespace SmsBroadcastReceiver
{
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = Int32.MaxValue)]
public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        ISharedPreferences pref =  PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (context);
        string number = pref.GetString ("Number", "0");

        Bundle b= intent.Extras;
        var pdus = b.Get("pdus");
        var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Java.Lang.Object>(pdus.Handle);
        var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[0].Handle)];
        JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[0].Handle, bytes);
        SmsMessage msg= SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu (bytes);

        if (msg.OriginatingAddress == number) {
            //send empty sms

            SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage (msg.OriginatingAddress, null, "Empty", null, null);
            InvokeAbortBroadcast ();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage (msg.OriginatingAddress, null,"Empty", null, null);
```

this should fix your problem.

```
if (msg.OriginatingAddress == number) {
  //send empty sms
  //Remove /Comment below statement from your code.`enter code here`
  SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage (msg.OriginatingAddress, null, "Empty", null, null);
  InvokeAbortBroadcast ();
}
```